# Importing one package to another package definition

Tags: java, swing, import, package

Can we import another package in the new package definition?

For e.g.

```
   package mypack2;

   import mypack1.*;

   **mypack2 methods declared later**
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just import the classes from the other package or make the other package into a jar file and import it to your project.

You need to put the full path when you import ex:

`Import com.project.package.class`